# printing part of an html page

Tags: html, css, printing, media

I'm making a pretty large data entry form in html (LAMP).

I need to print it on a pre-printed sheet. So the labels should not print.

Is there any easy CSS rule that states not to print certain elements? Or should I turn them (the labels) off one at a time programmatically?

Thanks!

PS: It must work on FF and IE at least.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a print stylesheet that hides (`visibility:hidden`) all the pre-printed data.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="print.css" media="print">
```

The rules in this stylesheet will only be applied during printing. You can, however, debug it (see what the results would be like without actually printing the page) by temporarily changing `media="print"` to `media="all"`.

*Read more [here](http://www.webcredible.co.uk/user-friendly-resources/css/print-stylesheet.shtml).*